# Git: svn log --stop-on-copy equivalent

Tags: git, svn, logging

Title says it all. So, how can I achive that functionality in git? Please don't give solutions involving too much scripting.

'svn log --stop-on-copy' outputs the log since the creation of the branch.

Comment: You'll probably have a better chance for an answer if you describe what that option actually does. Because a lot of people might know how to do what you want, but don't feel like looking up what that SVN option does -- and so don't know that they can help you.

Comment: @NevikRehnel edited the post so that people know what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have `experiment` branch created from `master` at some point.
If you want to see what is in your `experiment` branch that hasn’t yet been merged into your `master` you can use ranges of commits syntax:

```
git log master..experiment
```

See [Git Tools - Revision Selection](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection)

Comment: But it also show commits which are not there in experiment branch.

Comment: Any idea on how to do this after experiment has been merged? In this situation, git reports that there's nothing in experiment that isn't in master, so I guess master..experiment is not asking git the right question...